# Finding the location of a button in Stardew Valley with python OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

The problem that I am having is that the loop is instantly breaking right after it is run. I would expect this code to run until the main menu of the game comes up and the coop button is visible. I would then expect it to return the location of it via `loc`. However, this is not what is happening and I am unsure why that is the case.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyscreenshot
coop_button = cv2.imread("coop_button.png")
while True:
    img = np.array(pyscreenshot.grab().convert('RGB'))
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, coop_button, method=cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    print(res)
    loc = np.where(res >= .999)
    print(loc)
    if len(loc[0]) != 0:
        break
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: What IS happening?

Comment: @deets it is instantly detecting a match before the game has even started

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and the template? Also, be aware that you need to tune the threshold (.999 in your example, and better made a constant or parameter instead hard coded somewhere in code)?